# function expansion perpendicular to plane

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, hamiltonian

In thermodynamics, you sometimes want to calculate (a part of) the volume of the $6N$-dimensional phase space $\Omega(E)$, where $N$ is the particle number and $E$ is the energy. I'm trying to understand where the equation for that volume

$$\Omega(E) = \int \frac{dq~dp}{h^{3N}N!}\delta\left(E-H(q,p)\right)$$

comes from ($\delta(.)$ is the $\delta$-distribution). In a textbook, I read that one has to "expand the Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ perpendicular to the equienergy planes" where the equienergy planes are given by $H(q,p) = E = const.$

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to actually write down the necessary Taylor expansion. I hope this is enough information for you to show me how to do this.

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful to understand what you are getting at. You say it is not relevant, but if you want us to help you understand where a particular equation comes from, it would be helpful to know what equation we are talking about.

Comment: @BySymmetry I added the equation. Is this more helpful?

Comment: You do not understand where the equation you wrote comes from? Or you do not understand how to transform it in an integral without a $\delta$ function?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis As I wrote in my post, I wonder how to expand the Hamiltonian "perpendicular to the equienergy planes". If you know a derivation of the formula in my post which involves an expansion of $H$, please share it with me.

Comment: Mmmhmmm… I should have started with that but could you give the reference to the textbook you spoke of?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it is used with respect to your integral in the textbook you consulted, but «the expansion of $H$ perpendicular to the equi-energy surface», that I can write for you.

First, a linearisation of $H$ reads

$$H(p+\epsilon, q+\eta) = H(p,q) + \nabla_pH(p,q)\cdot\epsilon + \nabla_qH(p,q)\cdot\eta + \cdots$$

where

$$\newcommand{\partialder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\begin{align}
\nabla_pH&=\left(\partialder{H}{p_1}, \cdots, \partialder{H}{p_N}\right),\\
\nabla_qH&=\left(\partialder{H}{q_1}, \cdots, \partialder{H}{q_N}\right).
\end{align}$$

The notation $\nabla_pH(p,q)$ means all the derivatives are evaluated at the phase space point $(p,q)$ and the dot means the canonical scalar product.

Then, the surface $\mathcal{S}(E)$ of equi-energy $E$ is given by the implicit equation

$$H(p,q)=E.$$

From the linearisation, we can read that the normal vector to the equi-energy surface $S(E)$ at the phase space point $(p,q)$ is

$$n(p,q)=\big(\nabla_pH(p,q),\nabla_qH(p,q)\big).$$

Thus a linearisation of $H(p,q)$ in a direction orthogonal to $\mathcal{S}(E)$ means to look at the value of $H$ at the point shifted by $\lambda n(p,q)$ for an infinitesimal $\lambda$, and then to expand it in series of $\lambda$. At order 1,

$$H\big(p+\lambda\nabla_pH(p,q),q+\lambda\nabla_qH(p,q)\big) = H(p,q) + \big(\nabla_pH(p,q)^2 + \nabla_qH(p,q)^2\big)\lambda+\cdot$$

The square means the sum of the square of each component of the vector.